# Subscribe to Shared Album from iCloud for PC

Tags: ios, icloud, windows, photos, sharing

Q: How do I use iCloud for Windows to **accept an invitation for a Shared Photo Album  without an iOS device or a Mac**?

I have an Apple ID, I can see my iCloud files and photos with a web browser, and I can use the PC iCloud app to upload and download photos but **I do not have an iOS device or a Mac**.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot subscribe to a shared album without a Mac or an iOS device.

See this message from Apple when trying to subscribe to a shared photo album:

> **iCloud Photo Sharing is not available for this device**
>
> To subscribe to (sender's name)’s “Sample Photo Album Name” shared
>   album on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac, open your invitation
>   in the Mail app, and click the Subscribe button in the message.
>
> ---
>
> To subscribe you need to be signed in to iCloud on:
>
> - an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iOS 6 or later, or
> - a Mac with macOS 10.8.2 or later and iPhoto 9.4 or Aperture 3.4 or later

Comment: If I did have an iOS device and subscribed, and then later went to PC would the shared album be available?

Comment: @mattwilkie no, it won’t be visible in any browser without enabling “public website” in the album

Comment: ...sorry, I meant go to "the program [iCloud installed on a PC](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/ht204283)" not a web browser on PC

Comment: Yes that would work